# Exibir 3 Models em uma View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho 3 *Models* e preciso montar 2 (duas) listas e um botão "Gravar":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe: TBProduto:

```
public class TBProduto
{
    [Key]
    public int TBPRODUTOID { get; set; }      
    public string DSPRODUTO { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TBProdutoFornecedor> TBProdutoFornecedor { get; set; }

}
```

Classe TBFornecedor:

```
public TBFornecedor()
    [Key]
    public int TBFORNECEDORID { get; set; }
    public string NMFORNECEDOR { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TBProdutoFornecedor> TBProdutoFornecedor { get; set; }
```

Classe TBProdutoFornecedor:

```
public class TBProdutoFornecedor
{
    [Key]
    public int TBPRODUTOTBFORNECEDORID { get; set; }
    public int TBPRODUTOID { get; set; }
    public int TBFORNECEDORID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DTPRODUTOFORNECEDOR { get; set; }
    public virtual TBProduto Produtos { get; set; }
    public virtual TBFornecedor Fornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

**Controler**:

```
 public class ProdutoFornecedorController : Controller
{
     private IProdutoFornecedor _IRepositorio;

    public ProdutoFornecedorController()
        : this(new ProdutoFornecedorRepositorio())
    { 
    }

    public ProdutoFornecedorController(IProdutoFornecedor repositorio)
    {
        _IRepositorio = repositorio;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**PartialView - Produto**

```
@model IEnumerable<Lamar.Dominio.Entidade.TBProduto>
<select id="produto">
<option value="">Selecione um item</option>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option value="@item.CODPRODUTO">@item.DSPRODUTO</option>
}
```

**PartialView - Fornecedor**

```
@model IEnumerable<Lamar.Dominio.Entidade.TBFornecedor>
<select id="Selfornecedor">
<option value="">Selecione um item</option>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option value="@item.CODFORNECEDOR">@item.NMFORNECEDOR</option>
}
```

**View Index**

```
@model IEnumerable<Lamar.Dominio.Entidade.TBProdutoFornecedor>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Areas/Administrativo/Views/Shared/_AdministrativoLayout.cshtml";
```

}

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">FORNECEDOR</div><div class="col-md-2">@Html.Partial("_produto")</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">FORNECEDOR</div><div class="col-md-2">@Html.Partial("_fornecedor")</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn" value="">GRAVAR</button></div><div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Criei as listas de **Fornecedor** e **Produto** através de PartialView na pasta `Shared`.

O problema é que as listas sempre retornam nulas, não sei se pulei alguma etapa na hora de criar essas *Views*. No banco de dados tem Produtos e Fornecedores cadastrados e mesmo assim retorna nulo.

Comment: Você está usando Entity Framework?

Comment: Sim, Entity Framework 6

Comment: Ok, preciso do código das *Views* também.

Comment: Foi adicionada  as Views na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não passou os *Models* de possibilidades nas *Partials*. Não vai funcionar assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">FORNECEDOR</div><div class="col-md-2">@Html.Partial("_produto")</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">FORNECEDOR</div><div class="col-md-2">@Html.Partial("_fornecedor")</div>
</div>
```

O certo seria você carregar todas as possibilidades de clientes e fornecedores na *Action* `Index`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ProdutosPossiveis = contexto.Produtos.ToList();
    ViewBag.FornecedoresPossiveis = contexto.Fornecedores.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

E então usar assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">FORNECEDOR</div><div class="col-md-2">@Html.Partial("_produto", (IEnumerable<Produto>)ViewBag.ProdutosPossiveis)</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">FORNECEDOR</div><div class="col-md-2">@Html.Partial("_fornecedor", (IEnumerable<Fornecedor>)ViewBag.FornecedoresPossiveis)</div>
</div>
```